# Error when running sudo, getting a permission denied

Tags: permissions, sudo

I was installing GIT on my machine, when I `sudo` any thing, this error message appears:

```
sudo: must be setuid root
```

I tried from recovery mode to change permissions of `usr/bin/sudo` by:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

but the `chown` or `chmod` not working cause the file is read only.

Answer (score 8):

When starting in recovery mode your `/` file system is mounted read-only. 
So the first command must be

```
mount / -o remount,rw
```

after that the commands you found yourself will solve your problem.